# Не работает clear() WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Не работает метод clear() из Selenium WebDriver в поисковике (если я правильно понял, пишет - Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with).

Запустил для проверки работоспособности локально страничку с фреймами и полем ввода - метод отрабатывает нормально. В чем может быть проблема? Метод работает только с простыми формами?

```
package com.packt.webdriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class WebDriverNavigate {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.by");

    WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.name("btnK"));

    searchBox.sendKeys("Selenium WebDriver");
    button.click();
    searchBox.clear(); // метод очистки не работает
    searchBox.sendKeys("WTF?");
```

Comment: Правильно лн работает. Элемент должен быть в поле видимости. Я с таким сталкивался. Надо привести элемент в видимую область браузера, тогда ошибка не возникает.

Comment: Вы там хотите очистить сразу после нажатия. А что на странице в эти миллисекунды? Может, google уже скрыл searchBox?

Comment: Проблема не в том что "я хочу"... Проблема в том, что это учебный пример из книги, а я его разбираю. Если в книге не указаны таймауты перед выполнением другой команды, значит это как бы и не надо. Хочу разобраться почему не работает. Читал что метод clear() работает не всегда и довольно разборчивый... P.S. Что значит "перевести элемент в видимую область" - строка поиска находится не в видимой области?

Comment: Да в учебниках могут быть ошибки - это раз. Сайт google.by мог измениться - это два.

Comment: Если элемент за пределами экрана, скрыт (display: none), невидим - (visibility: hidden), то найти его в драйвере можно, но нажать или очистить - нельзя. Будет ошибка, именно вот такая.

Comment: Да, согласен. Вы можете на этом сайте в данный сделать подобные действия и подсказать как добиться того результата, который нужен (удалить первую фразу, добавить вторую)?

Comment: Не вижу по инспектору элементов, что поле поиска скрыто или невидимо..((

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56373/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-princeoff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы ваш код работал, ищите и нажимайте кнопку поиска после ввода текста в поле:

```
package com.packt.webdriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class WebDriverNavigate {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.by");

    WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

    searchBox.sendKeys("Selenium WebDriver");
    WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.name("btnG"));
    button.click();
    searchBox.clear();
    searchBox.sendKeys("WTF?");
```

А вообще для поиска в google достаточно ввести текст и убрать фокус с поля поиска, результаты должны автоматически отобразиться

Comment: Вы знаете, ваш код отработал верно в плане метода clear(). И дело даже не в том где объявить переменную - он и в моем случае сработает. Дело в том, что у вас значение кнопки "btnG" (почему она? Откуда вы ее взяли если она скрыта на начальной странице - display: none) а у меня "btnK" (а вот эта кнопка отображается, это кнопка "Поиск в google") и я не могу теперь понять почему так... P.S. по поводу "ввести текст и убрать фокус" можете на примере показать, не совсем понял...

Comment: `btnG` появляется на странице когда вы вводите текст в поле поиска

Comment: Давайте я еще раз попробую объяснить свой вопрос (видимо плохо умею задавать).

Comment: Изначально я продумываю шаги теста мысленно затем перекладываю их на код. У меня есть страница поисковика с полем ввода текста (name = q) и кнопка сабмита (name = btnK). В процессе того как я перекладываю шаги теста на код я беру эти параметры и подставляю в код. Откуда я должен знать, что кнопка сабмита после ввода текста скрывается и заменяется на другую кнопку в виде лупы и соответственно с другим именем (name=btnG)?

Comment: В общем ладно, чтобы не разводить демагогию, гугл сделала кнопку btnK, которая нафиг никому не нужна а реально используется кнопка в виде лупы btnG.

Answer (score 1):

Все работает правильно. Ошибка в вашем коде.

Когда выполняется оператор `searchBox.sendKeys("Selenium WebDriver")`, элемент `btnk` становится скрытым.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код из инспектора:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Элемент `<div class="jsb"....>` имеет атрибут `display: none;`, входящий в него `btnk` - тоже.

При попытке нажатия на кнопку `btnk` возникает указанная в вопросе ошибка. Нельзя "нажимать" на то, что находится вне границ экрана, имеет атрибуты `display: none;` или `visibility: hidden;`.

Comment: Да, спасибо, это правильно - кнопка скрывается после ввода текста, но вопрос был в другом - почему метод clear() - который никак не привязан к кнопке, которая скрыта - не отрабатывал, верно?

Comment: Ответ как в этом и состоит. Метод clear () не выполняется, потому что дело до него не доходит - программа падает на предыдущем операторе. NotVisibleExeption - фатальная ошибка.

Comment: Не пойму, как вы запускаете программу? В отладчике все это видно.

Comment: Я видел это исключение в отладчике и написал об этом в своем вопросе. Только из отладчика не ясно к какому элементу или на какой строке это исключение возникает... Объясните, я буду рад любой помощи на данном этапе.

Comment: Предыдущая строчка перед исключение в отладчике всегда указывает на ту строку, которая вызвала исключение?

Comment: Да там ясно указывается номер строки, где произошло. Вы чем пользуетесь?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Пользуюсь eclipse.P.S. что-то не могу тут скриншот прикрепить к комментарию, наверное только к ответам можно...